# Meteor JS Routing on Angular 2 Tutorial doesn't work

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to make the socially tutorial from the meteor js web but I'm stuck on the step 5 **Routing & Multiple Views**
When I click on the link to see "party details" the javascript console says that the route doesn't exists.
This is the code from the view that has the link.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/party', party._id]">{{party.name}}</a>
```

And this is the code from the routes:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: PartiesListComponent },
  { path: 'party/:partyId', component: PartyDetailsComponent }
];
```

This is the output from the console.

```
browser_adapter.js:84 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'party;_str=57df4efc74ee85f397a687f3'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is that `party._id` is actually an object, not the id primitive. If I had to put my money on it, I'd say this it what it looks like

```
party: {
  _id: {
    _str: '57df4efc74ee85f397a687f3'
  }
}
```

When you add an object into the `routerLink` array, it becomes a [matrix parameter](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html) for the previous path segment. So if the above *is* the actual structure, then would result in

```
/party;_str=57df4efc74ee85f397a687f3
```

which is the problem you are facing. If you want to just add the id value to the path, then you should extract the `_str`

```
<a [routerLink]="['/party', party._id._str]">
```

This will give you the route

```
/party/57df4efc74ee85f397a687f3
```

which is what you want.

**See Also:**

- Angular docs on [Route Parameters](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters)

Comment: Dude thank you very much, I was trying everything for hours (Well, not everything) Thank you!

Comment: Seriously. I thought I was going crazy. I went through step 5 in the tutorial twice to make sure all my code was correct. Thanks!