# Difference in _id values in mongo, and how to handle them (angular 2 meteor tutorial)

Tags: mongodb, angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm doing the tutorial at https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/routing-and-multiple-views and realise some of my route links were not working.

Initially I thought this was the solution ([Meteor JS Routing on Angular 2 Tutorial doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692286/meteor-js-routing-on-angular-2-tutorial-doesnt-work)), converting them into strings but that didnt work either. i dug a little deeper and realised this: the route links works for data inserted through the app but not for data inserted through the console as they had `_id` fields with an `ObjectId` in it.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5859f7d5a8aeb662e0e3eff9"), "name" : "A new party", 
  "description" : "From the mongo console!", "location" : "In the DB" }
```

vs

```
{ "_id" : "67dswyFrT3Bt3kHED", "name" : "inserted works", 
  "description" : "inserted works", "location" : "inserted works" }
```

How can I handle both kind of `_id` data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an explanation of why the two are different: [Meteor.Collection.ObjectID() vs MongoDB ObjectId()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318184/meteor-collection-objectid-vs-mongodb-objectid)

Basically Meteor can use Mongo ObjectId's, but it uses simpler strings because it makes it easier to put _id fields in URL's etc

Normally only your app will ever modify the data, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but how do i retrieve the data that are inserted through the console? even converting it to string doesnt work.

Comment: Yes, you have a short term problem there, but data inserted in the console isn't a normal use case for any application. You could try specifying the _id as you insert the records in the console.